# Can a Lua function using the colon syntactic sugar be defined inside a table?

Tags: lua, syntax

Is there an alternative syntax for

```lua
Account = {}

function Account:new (o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

where `new` could be put directly into the table constructor for `Account`, and where the function gains an implicit `self` variable?

Or must one use a `self` parameter (or equivalent), and do it the following way?

```lua
Account = {
    new = function (self, o)
        o = o or {}
        setmetatable(o, self)
        self.__index = self
        return o
    end
}
```

Comment: Lua doesn't even have `++`, you should be grateful to be able to define functions in two ways.

Comment: Lol, I am grateful, but also curious.

Comment: Yes, you must use an explicit `self` in the second case.

Comment: In other words, I understood it correctly, and there is no alternative to the explicit self? 
I'd be okay with that, I am/was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No syntactic sugar is available for function definitions within table constructors. This includes `function name (args) body end` for `name = function (args) body end`, and by extension the colon syntax.

You must use an explicit first function parameter (it does not *need* to be named `self`, but that is good practice).

As you have noted, this will work, as colon syntax for function calls is a separate form of syntactic sugar.

> A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once.

Lua 5.4:

- [§3.4.9 - Table Constructors](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9)
- [§3.4.10 – Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10)
- [§3.4.11 - Function Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.11)